# Expand animation from bottom to top

Tags: android

i used the code:

```
 public static void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targtetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {


        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                Transformation t) {

            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int)(targtetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

the effect is from top to bottom,i want to use the animation from bottom to top

Comment: Targeting Android 2.x or 4.x?

Comment: i  am use Target 4.x,

Comment: any solution @pengwang ?